# Suppress legend item scaling (layers panel QGIS)

Tags: qgis, user-interface

Is it possible to suppress the legend item scaling in the layers panel of QGIS 3.4.x?

[image]

I'ts a nice functionality, but confusing when using the magnifier > 100%

Comment: I don't think this feature exists. There are various bug/issue reports relating layer panel item scaling, for example [this one](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19282). If you look for more bug reports, you may find some workarounds or information about the different controls currently available.